# I have a sorted list, and I would like to count the number of occurrence of each number without using count() function

Tags: python-3.x, count

I have a sorted list, and I would like to count the number of occurrences of each number without using the `count()` function.

```
sameItem = 0
startPosition = 1

sortedList  = [13, 15, 15, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 26, 26, 26, 27, 27, 27, 28]

for i in range(1, len(sortedList)):

    item1 = sortedList[i - 1]
    item2 = sortedList[i]
    countItems = 1
    sameItem = countItems

    if item1 == item2:
        startPosition = i
        while (sortedList[i - 1] == sortedList[startPosition]):
           sameItem += 1
           startPosition += 1

    else:
        sameItem = countItems

    print(str(item1) + " appears " + str(sameItem) + " times")
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: One way to do it is to make an counter array and make it the size of the largest number. so in your case int countArray[29]; Now you can do something like countArray[13]++ to count the number of times 13 appears. Then sum up the values of the countArray.

Comment: This might help you. [Count occurrence in sorted array](https://www.cdn.geeksforgeeks.org/count-number-of-occurrences-or-frequency-in-a-sorted-array/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
for k, g in groupby(sortedList):
    print('%s appears %d times' % (k, len(list(g))))
```

Or if you prefer not to use any library functions:

```
count = 1
for i, n in enumerate(sortedList):
    if i == len(sortedList) - 1 or n != sortedList[i + 1]:
        print('%s appears %d times' % (n, count))
        count = 1
    else:
        count += 1
```

Or if you prefer not to use any function at all (well actually `print` is a function too but I don't think you can do without it):

```
last = None
for n in sortedList:
    if n != last:
        if last is not None:
            print('%s appears %d times' % (last, count))
        last = n
        count = 1
    else:
        count += 1
print('%s appears %d times' % (last, count))
```

All of the above output:

```
13 appears 1 times
15 appears 2 times
17 appears 1 times
18 appears 4 times
19 appears 1 times
20 appears 4 times
21 appears 1 times
22 appears 4 times
23 appears 3 times
24 appears 2 times
26 appears 3 times
27 appears 3 times
28 appears 1 times
```

Comment: But i would like to convert it to mips...so i wont be using any libraries...
is there a way to do it with my current code (with a little bit of tweaking)?

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer with a solution that uses no library functions then.

Comment: is there a way to do it without enumerate? cuz i'm trying to write an algorithm without any functions used..

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution that uses no function at all then.

Comment: i have added my current solution below..they are mostly correct, except for the last few output

Answer (score 0):

i = 1

check = False

sameItem = 0

while (i < len(sortedList)):

```
if sortedList[i-1] == sortedList[i]:
    check = True
    j = i

    while (sortedList[i-1] == sortedList[j]) and (check == True):
        sameItem += 1
        j += 1

        if (sortedList[i-1] != sortedList[j]):
            check = False
        i = j

    print(str(sortedList[i-1]) + " appears " + str(sameItem) + " times")

else:
    sameItem = 1
    print(str(sortedList[i-1]) + " appears " + str(sameItem) + " times")

i += 1
```

Comment: Your solution is unnecessarily complicated to be frank. There's no need to have maintain two indexes when you're always comparing only the adjacent items. The `check` flag also doesn't make any sense.